# MySQL - Combine two tables into third without duplicates

Tags: mysql, select, insert, duplicates

I am having a hard time wrapping my mind around a concept here. What I have are three tables that are identical structure.  I need `table 1` to be combined with `table 2` and `INSERT INTO` `table 3`.  My issue:

`table 1` and `table 2` have duplicate content, EXCEPTION BEING their `ID`.  I am not using the `ID` for anything other than `AI` however, so that really is not a concern.

An example of what I am looking to accomplish is:

```
                        original TABLE 1
 _________________________________________________________
|    ID   |      Col 2     |     Col 3    |      Col 4    |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|   1     |     stuff_1    |     stuff_2  |     stuff_3   |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|   2     |     stuff_x    |     stuff_y  |     stuff_z   |
|_________________________________________________________|
```

Combine with

```
                        original TABLE 2
 _________________________________________________________
|    ID   |      Col 2     |     Col 3    |      Col 4    |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|   3     |     stuff_1    |     stuff_2  |     stuff_3   |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|   4     |     stuff_a    |     stuff_b  |     stuff_c   |
|_________________________________________________________|
```

To make

```
combined TABLE 3 (notice ID's are not counted in duplicate check)
 _________________________________________________________
|    ID   |      Col 2     |     Col 3    |      Col 4    |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|   ?     |     stuff_1    |     stuff_2  |     stuff_3   |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|   ?     |     stuff_x    |     stuff_y  |     stuff_z   |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|   ?     |     stuff_a    |     stuff_b  |     stuff_c   |
|_________________________________________________________|
```

I have tried `insert into table 3 select * from table 2;`  and THEN doing a `insert ignore` from table 1. I've tried `replace into` as well, but because I am omitting the ID, those don't work because the column count is off.  Does anyone have any ideas how to combine these two into the third table while dealing with the ID issue?  I will reiterate that it really does not matter what the ID's are as they will not ever be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` to flatten out the duplicates while leaving an `ID` value.

This will give you unique `Col1`, `Col2` and `Col3` values, and will set the `ID` to the minimum `ID` value for any rows that were merged as duplicated:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT MIN(ID), Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Table1
  UNION SELECT ID, Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Table2
) Table1And2
GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3
```

With your posted data, the result should be this:

```
ID    Col1     Col2     Col3
--    -------  -------  -------
 1    stuff_1  stuff_2  stuff_3
 2    stuff_a  stuff_b  stuff_c
 4    stuff_x  stuff_y  stuff_z
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `select distinct` instead of `group by`?

Comment: In this case I don't think so. My first thought was `DISTINCT`, then because he's taking values from two tables I thought `UNION`, but he's checking for uniqueness along three of the four columns - the `ID` doesn't have to be distinct.

Comment: This did work, although I had to allocate more resources for the query ...  It pegged the data server for almost an hour given that there was about 500,000 rows in each `table1` and `table2`  --  This was so that we could archive these tables and start fresh ...  Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

I added an unique index on col2, col3, col4 on table3

```
alter table t3 add unique u1 (col2, col3, col4);
```

and then did

```
insert ignore into t3 select * from t1 union select * from t2;
```

to get

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+
| id   | col2    | col3    | col4    |
+------+---------+---------+---------+
|    1 | stuff_1 | stuff_2 | stuff_3 |
|    2 | stuff_x | stuff_y | stuff_z |
|    4 | stuff_a | stuff_b | stuff_c |
+------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The Goal is to have the contents of Table1 Inserted into Table3, and the contents of Table2, which are not in Table1, to be inserted into Table3. The following query does exactly that.

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3
  FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3
  FROM Table2
  WHERE (Col1, Col2, Col3) NOT IN (SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Table 1);
```